# How to count how many articles belongs which category?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this relationships:

ARTICLES

```
 public function category()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Categories');
    }
```

CATEGORY have translations

```
public function c_translations()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\CategoryTranslations', 'category_id');
  }
```

In articles i have category id, also in translations i have category_id. So how can i count how many articles have each category. Any suggestion?

```
 $articles = Articles::all();
      foreach($articles as $article ){
      $articles_category = Articles::where('id',$article->id)->withCount('category')->first();

      }
```

I tried this but always get 0 for all of categories

Comment: Your question still doesn't make any sense. Can you give some examples what you need?

Comment: i want to display all categories from database with number of articles for that categories

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define a [`hasMany`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) relation in your `Category` model as:

```
public function articles()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Article');
}
```

Then you can use [`withCount`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) to query it as:

```
$categories = Category::withCount('articles')->get();
```

Pass it to your view and then you can access the no. of articles of category as:

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)
  <li>{{ category->title }}</li>
  <li>{{ category->articles_count }}</li>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`withCount()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) method to count relation.

```
Model::where('id', $id)->withCount('relation')->first();
```

> If you want to count the number of results from a relationship without actually loading them you may use the `withCount` method, which will place a `{relation}_count` column on your resulting models.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a group by statement.
You select category_id,COUNT(*) FROM articles GROUP BY category_id
This will return the number of articles for each category_id